# POST item JSON to API using Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to HTTP POST an item to an API using Scrapy. In my pipeline I have:

```
Request( url, method='POST',
    body=json.dumps(item),
    headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'} )
```

This does not work. The error is:

```
{ some JSON } is not JSON serializable
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to send as body? what's the type of `item`?

Comment: I am just trying to send the item returned by the spider as JSON to an API. I guess the item isn't JSON?

Comment: You can use `body=json.dumps(dict(item))`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in p[aul trmbrth's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026017/post-item-json-to-api-using-scrapy/74770749#comment38972160_25026017), instead of

```
body=json.dumps(item)
```

use

```
body=json.dumps(dict(item))
```

So your code would become:

```
Request( url, method='POST',
    body=json.dumps(dict(item)),
    headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'} )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `JsonRequest` from `from scrapy.http` as follows:

```
JsonRequest(
    url=<url>,
    method='POST',
    # Replace with your item or dict(item)
    data=item
)
```

Behind it calls `json.dumps` on the dictionary you pass to the `data` parameter so you first might want to make sure that your `item` that you're trying to send is json serializable.