# Scrapy post request does not work, but normal python request does

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I am trying to get some data regarding some flights from WizzAir. I started to use scrapy as I want to extend the scraper to other companies and domains. The problem is that when I make an API request to WizzAir API I always get 403 due to akamai bot detector, but with normal python request the whole thing works.

I always get 403 and 404 with the scrapy approach.

I have looked in multiple places:

- [POST item JSON to API using Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25026017/4424636)
- [Scrapy API request 403 error issue. Works with requests, but not scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71086762/4424636)

But I cannot make the scrapy approach work.

The normal requests [approach](https://pastebin.com/JGQmbWkX) works, but the scrapy [approach](https://pastebin.com/dWyHXL5J) does not.

Normal requests:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json
import sys

# This is to set the payload to each price type.
def alter_price(price_type, flights):
    if price_type == "wdc":
        [flight.update({"priceType": "wdc"}) for flight in flights]
    else:
        [flight.update({"priceType": "regular"}) for flight in flights]
    return flights

headers = {
    'authority': 'be.wizzair.com',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'origin': 'https://wizzair.com',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'referer': 'https://wizzair.com/en-gb/flights/timetable',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,hu-HU;q=0.8,hu;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6'
}

# If you need data other than Budapest:
data = {"flightList":[{"departureStation":"", # Change this
                       "arrivalStation":"",
                       "from":"",
                       "to":""},
                      {"departureStation":"",
                       "arrivalStation":"", # and this
                       "from":"",
                       "to":""}],"priceType":"","adultCount":1,"childCount":0,"infantCount":0}

# These were collected by hand from the wizzair website, because I couldn't download them with code.
# The other airport is always Budapest as defined in the payload.
destinations = ["CRL",]

data_list = []
base = datetime.today()
# Here you can set how many periods you want to download (period = 42 days)
for period in range(6):
    # Only a maximum of 42 days is supported by wizzair.
    data["flightList"][0]["from"] = (base + timedelta(days = period * 42)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    data["flightList"][1]["from"] = (base + timedelta(days = period * 42)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    data["flightList"][0]["to"] = (base + timedelta(days = (period + 1) * 42)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    data["flightList"][1]["to"] = (base + timedelta(days = (period + 1) * 42)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    for price_type in ["regular"]:
        data["priceType"] = price_type
        print(f"Downloading started with the following params for all destinations: {period}, {price_type}")
        for destination in destinations:
            data["flightList"][0]["arrivalStation"] = destination
            data["flightList"][1]["departureStation"] = destination

            response = requests.post('https://be.wizzair.com/14.3.0/Api/search/timetable', headers=headers, json={
                "flightList": [
                    {
                        "departureStation": "GVA",
                        "arrivalStation": "OTP",
                        "from": "2022-12-16",
                        "to": "2023-01-01"
                    }
                ],
                "priceType": "regular",
                "adultCount": 1,
                "childCount": 0,
                "infantCount": 0
            })

            if response.status_code == 200:
                data_list.append(alter_price(price_type, response.json()["outboundFlights"]))
            else:
                print("HTTP status: ", response.status_code)
                print("Something went wrong with this payload: ", data)

flat_list = [item for sublist in data_list for item in sublist]
print(flat_list)
```

Scrapy spider:

```
import json
import sys
import time
from typing import List, Dict

import requests
from scrapy import Spider, Request, FormRequest
from datetime import date, timedelta
from copy import deepcopy

from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror import HttpError
from twisted.internet.error import DNSLookupError
from twisted.internet.error import TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse


class WizzairSpider(Spider):
    name = 'WizzAir'
    allowed_domains = ['wizzair.com']
    start_url = 'https://wizzair.com'

    # 42 is supported by WizzAir -> 30 just to be safe
    MAX_DELTA = timedelta(days=30)

    PRICE_TYPES = [{'priceType': 'regular'}]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, **kwargs)
        self.sources = ['GVA']
        self.destinations = ['OTP']
        self.intervals = [2]

    def _prepare_request(self, source: str, destination: str, departure_date: date) -> List[Dict]:
        def apply_extras(base_template: dict, extras: dict) -> dict:
            base_template.update(extras)
            return base_template

        arrival_date = departure_date + WizzairSpider.MAX_DELTA
        base_request = {
            "flightList": [
                {
                    "departureStation": source,
                    "arrivalStation": destination,
                    "from": departure_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                    "to": arrival_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                }
            ],
            "priceType": "",
            "adultCount": 1,
            "childCount": 0,
            "infantCount": 0
        }

        return list(map(lambda extra: apply_extras(deepcopy(base_request), extra), WizzairSpider.PRICE_TYPES))

    def start_requests(self):
        today = date.today()

        for time_distance in self.intervals:
            departure_date = today + timedelta(days=time_distance)

            for source in self.sources:
                for destination in self.destinations:
                    if source == destination:
                        continue

                    for payload in self._prepare_request(source, destination, departure_date):
                        yield Request(
                            url='https://wizzair.com/14.3.0/Api/search/timetable',
                            method='POST',
                            callback=self.parse,
                            body=json.dumps(payload),
                            headers={
                                "authority": "be.wizzair.com",
                                "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                                "origin": "https://wizzair.com",
                                "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36",
                                "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                                "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
                                "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
                                "referer": "https://wizzair.com/en-gb/flights/timetable",
                                "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                                "accept-language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,hu-HU;q=0.8,hu;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6"
                            }
                        )

    def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
        print("got error")
        # log all failures
        self.logger.error(repr(failure))

        # in case you want to do something special for some errors,
        # you may need the failure's type:

        if failure.check(HttpError):
            # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
            # you can get the non-200 response
            response = failure.value.response
            self.logger.error('HttpError on %s', response.url)

        elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            # this is the original request
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('DNSLookupError on %s', request.url)

        elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('TimeoutError on %s', request.url)

    def parse(self, response: HtmlResponse, **kwargs):
        print('status code', response.status)
        print('------', response.body)
```

Comment: typo.... the url you use in your `start_requests` method is missing the `be` before the domain

Comment: gosh, thanks for the keen eyes. I haven't even noticed the small `be` missing, even if that was the most important stuff -_-

Comment: Voting to close as this was caused by a typo

Answer (score -2):

Try using `scrapy.FormReqeust` and pass your data to formdata attribute

```
yield FormRequest(
url='https://wizzair.com/14.3.0/Api/search/timetable',
callback=self.parse,
formdata=payload,
headers={
    "authority": "be.wizzair.com",
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "origin": "https://wizzair.com",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36",
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "referer": "https://wizzair.com/en-gb/flights/timetable",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,hu-HU;q=0.8,hu;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6"
}
```

)